# gitlab repo without knowledge of your remote on github

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-remote

I have a project which is published on Gitlab. But I also want to have it on Github as a private repo... I just have a question... if I clone it locally and then add a remote to the Github repository... this information will be accessible from the Gitlab repo? If so, how could I get it? I mean... assuming the Github remote is called `remote_github` and someone clones the gitlab repo locally when I run `git remote` it doesn't output `remote_github`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the list of remotes is specific to your local clone. It is stored in `.git/config` (under `[remote "origin"]` and similarly-named sections for other remotes) and is not shared with any of the remotes. So the Gitlab server will not know that you also have pushed it to GitHub.